# Different return by generics statements, javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

Is there way to return different values by **generic statements?**

Example:

```
//How should i write function, which will be used as follows?:
type FooType<T> = T | T[]
let baz: FooType<Object[]> = Foo<Object[]>('bar') // returns: [{bar: 'bar'}]
let bazbar: FooType<Object> = Foo<Object>('bar') // returns: { bar: 'bar' }
```

Comment: You can't return a different value based off the generic type. You need your input to be different for each of the cases.

Comment: @GorkaHernandez, thanks for help. I'll try on the input parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> //How should i write function, which will be used as follows?:
> type FooType<T> = T | T[]
> let baz: FooType<Object[]> = Foo<Object[]>('bar') // returns: [{bar: 'bar'}]
> let bazbar: FooType<Object> = Foo<Object>('bar') // returns: { bar: 'bar' }
> ```

You can't. The types in TypeScript are just another layer on top of the code. The code is not aware of these types. It's only the compiler that checks wether the code you write matches the types you've added.

So the code in your function `Foo` has no clue wether it's expected to return an `Object` or an `Object[]`. You have to tell it through the arguments.

How about `Foo<Object[]>(['bar'])`? that should be as simple as possible. 
You pass an array, you get an array.

And in the function you can determine the return type by a simple `Array.isArray(arg)`

Comment: Thanks for a reply!